# A block slightly moves down

Tags: html, css

One block at the page slightly moves down. As you can see in the screenshot, an anchor moves this block. But I did not set any height for it.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVGuL.png)

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>Life in Arena</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" >
</head>

<body>

        <header>

            <div id="mid-header">
                <div id="top-image-block">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" id="top-image"></a>
                </div>
                <ul id="main-menu">
                    <li class="top-menu-list"><a href="#" class="top-menu-link">LIAPEDIA</a></li>
                    <li class="top-menu-list"><a href="#" class="top-menu-link">GUIDES</a></li>
                    <li class="top-menu-list"><a href="#" class="top-menu-link">ABOUT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </header>


        <div id="main-block">
            <div id="wide-column">

            </div>

            <div id="small-column">

            </div>

        </div>

        <footer>
            <div id="mid-footer">
                <img src="images/links.png" id="links-label">
                <div id="social-media-buttons">
                    <ul id="sm-list">
                        <li class="sm-button"><a href="http://vk.com/lifeinarena" target="_blank" class="sm-link"><img src="images/socvk.png"></a></li>
                        <li class="sm-button"><a href="https://twitter.com/LifeInArena" target="_blank" class="sm-link"><img src="images/soctwitter.png"></a></li>
                        <li class="sm-button"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCe04DzYZgUIYzwXqZFF1_mA" target="_blank" class="sm-link"><img src="images/socyt.png"</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <img src="images/wanttotelussomething.png" id="feedback-label">
                <div id="feedback-button">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank" id="feedback-link">Feedback</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:
    body
    {
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #292829, #2e182a);
        overflow-x: auto;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

```
/* H E A D E R*/
header
{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #1a1818;
    width: 100%;
    height: 131px;
    margin: 0;
}

#mid-header
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1171px;
    height: 131px;
    background-color: #1a1818;
}

#top-image-block
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#top-image
{
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#main-menu 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
}

.top-menu-list
{
    float: left;
    height: 131px;
}

.top-menu-list a 
{
    color: #b0b0b0;
    padding: 0px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 131px;
    font-family: Arial, "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.top-menu-list a:hover
{
    color: #eeeeee;
}


/* C O N T E N T*/
#main-block
{
    display: block;
    width: 1171px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#wide-column
{
    display: block;
    width: 812px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #22181d;  
    float:left;
}

#small-column
{
    display: block;
    width: 318px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #22181d;  
    float:left;
}

/* F O O T E R*/
footer
{
    background-color: #000000;
    min-width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 350px;
}

#mid-footer
{ 
    width: 1171px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 160px;
    padding: 20px 15px;

}

#sm-list 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sm-button
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.sm-button a 
{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#feedback-button
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #1a84dd;  

}

#feedback-link
{
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 19px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 60px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: Arial, "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

The anchor is contained in a block with id="top-image-block".

The block that is moved down by the anchor has id="main-block".

Comment: Can you host this in JSFiddle or something? It'll be much easier for everyone

Comment: It's not the image. It's the `#top-image-block` div.

Comment: Jerry, https://jsfiddle.net/8onzw9g4/1/

Comment: @ScottMarcus I removed this div an left only the image and it worked out. But what is actually wrong about that div?

Comment: I suspect that even though that div has a `float:left` rule applied to it, that there wasn't enough room for it on the first line because it's width was still 100%. You could also try putting it back in, but adding `display:inline-block;` to the rule for it, which would cause it to only be as wide as its content.

Comment: @ScottMarcus display: inline-block only causes the bottom part go ![under the footer](http://cs630026.vk.me/v630026344/1c2df/XiTUDex1Fek.jpg).

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's because you have the div set to `float:`.  Either way, the issue is that div elements are block elements and block elements are always 100% of the width of their parent element -- making yours too wide to fit on the same line as the rest of the header.  The only ways to change that would be to set a width for the div (but this not always easy because you'd want to use a relative value) or change its display to `inline-block`

Comment: @ScottMarcus well, I'll just get rid of the div then. Thank you!